# I'm attempting to write a Taylor-expansion calculator in Java, but the program doesn't calculate correctly

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Java program that will calculate a cosine value with the following equation:
[image]

The code to my program is located below. I don't appear to have any errors in my program however no matter what values that I set `x` and `k` to, I get the answer `Infinity` and I cannot figure out what I've done wrong.

The way that the code works, is that the console asks you for a value for `x` and then a value for `k`. Then the idea is to have Java compare the result of the equation (the method `cosine` in the script) with the `Math.cos()` function.

The method `cosine` is split up into two parts, `cosinenumerator` and `cosinedenominator` which is then divided with each other to become `cosineresult` at the end.

The loop for `cosinedenominator` is supposed to emulate a "factorial" in the equation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cosine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner consolecosine = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter x value:");
        double x = consolecosine.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter k value:");
        int k = consolecosine.nextInt();
        double cosineresult = cosine(x, k);
        System.out.println("Using the Math.cos function yields: " + Math.cos(90));
        System.out.println("Using the Taylor expansion equation yields: " + cosineresult);
    }
    public static double cosine(double x, int k) {
        double cosineresult = 0;
        double cosinenumerator = 0;
        double cosinedenominator =0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
            cosinenumerator += Math.pow((-1),i) * Math.pow(x, (2*i));
        }
        for(j = 0; j <= (2*i); j++) {
            cosinedenominator *= (2*j);
        }
        cosineresult = cosinenumerator / cosinedenominator;
        return cosineresult;
    }
}
```

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I see. Do you have any suggestions for how else I could write this? It wouldn't accept "^" when I first tried it out.

Comment: @Woel ^ is XOR in C-derived languages including Java. You should use the fact that (-1)^k is +1 if k is even and -1 if odd. The logic of your code is unfortunately also completely wrong... please have another look at the formula and compare it with your code.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I have a strong feeling that it might be the loop for the factorial that is not correct. Could it be that the upper limit should be set to "k" so that the loop becomes `for(j = 0; j <= k; j++)`?

Comment: Well... not quite. You only calculate the factorial once, and divide the whole series by it at the end. That doesn't seem to match the given formula.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Do you mean that since `j` starts at 0, then all iterations in the loop will be multiplied by 0 as well?

Comment: `Math.pow` works for negative bases as it should.

Comment: The factorial loop itself is also wrong; beside that, there is a potential problem with overflow. Unfortunately there are simply too many problems with your code. Please try to read a beginner's Java programming book before diving into writing a reasonably complex piece of code.

Comment: looks to me that you're multiplying cosinedenominator which is 0 by 2j, thereby ending up with a cosinedenominator of 0, which should cause an exception

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version (note that x is in radians; not degrees):

`cosine(Math.PI, 15)` yields -1.0000000000000002, which is about right.

```
public static double cosine(double x, int k) {
    double cosineresult = 0;
    double cosinedenominator = 1; // initial value 0! = 1; overflows at k = 86
    int j = 2; // next multiplier in denominator factorial (skip 1)
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        double cosinenumerator = Math.pow((-1),i) * Math.pow(x, (2 * i));
        // Continue calculation of factorial from last value
        while (j <= 2 * i) {
            cosinedenominator *= j++;
        }
        cosineresult += cosinenumerator / cosinedenominator;
    }
    return cosineresult;
}
```